# Add and remove classes with event click in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to add one class or another with a click event, I'm using the angular ngClass, but it doesn't work for me.
When you click on the "li" element, it calls a function that changes the value of the "isExpandedConectivity" variable, but does nothing.

Component.html:

```
 <li class="nav-item" (click)="changeCollapsed()" aria-controls="collapseUsuarios">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">
                <span class="w-20px text-center mr-2">
                    <i class="fad fa-analytics"></i>
                </span>
                Conectividad
                <span class="w-100">
                    <i [ngClass]="'fad float-right isExpandedConectividad ? fa-chevron-down : fa-chevron-right"></i>
                </span>
            </a>
            <ul id="collapseConectividad" [collapse]="!isCollapsedConectividad" [isAnimated]="true" class="nav flex-column ml-5">
                <li class="nav-item">Tareas</li>
                <li class="nav-item">Diario</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
```

Component.ts:

```
export class SidebarComponent {
  isCollapsedTrabajo = false;
  isCollapsedUsuarios = false;
  isCollapsedConectividad = false;
  isExpandedConectividad = false;

  changeCollapsed(): void{
    this.isCollapsedConectividad = !this.isCollapsedConectividad;
    this.isExpandedConectividad = !this.isExpandedConectividad;
    console.log(this.isExpandedConectividad);
  }
}
```

Comment: I think it may be just [class], that works for me at least

Comment: also you have an unmatched: ' it looks like

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can separate out the statically applied classed and dynamically applied classes as such -

```
<i class="fad float-right" [ngClass]="isExpandedConectividad ? 'fa-chevron-down' : 'fa-chevron-right'"></i>
```

Check comparable [StackBlitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hwupag)

You can check the [usage of ngClass here](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass). In your case, the boolean was being evaluated under single quotes - ' '

Answer (score 1):

I always do the following:

Html:

```
 <button (click)="onClick()">
```

TS:

```
activeClass: boolean;    
onClick() {this.activeClass = !this.activeClass}
```

And again in Html:

```
<div [ngClass]="{cssClass1: activeClass, cssClass2: !activeClass}">
```

You can add as many classes as you wish allthough a boolean won't be enough then ^^

Answer (score 0):

```
[class.yourclassename]="isExpandedConectivity"
```

and if this condition is true, the class will be added